# access: displaying data on a report

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have a report that is attached to a query

i want to display the contents of a query. there are three columns. i made a list box but it looks weird:
[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/2245/52036335.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/2245/52036335.png)

i dont want the scroll bars, i just need the three fields from a query to be displayed regularly just as they would be in a spread sheet or grid

Comment: This is not a programming question. It does not belong on SO. It's also a really, really elementary end-user question, not even a "super user" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your report's Detail section, create a text box (not a list box) for each of those 3 fields in your query.

It might be easier to get oriented by creating an autoform based on the query.